# Recursion with Loop and break

Tags: java

I am designing one recursive method which has an for loop and break inside and expecting to break the loop after certain condition met. 
Following is piece of code

```
public static UIComponent findElem(UIComponent component){
UIComponent comp = null;
for(UIComponent child : component.getChildren()){
    if(child instanceof RichSelectBooleanRadio){
        RichSelectBooleanRadio radioButton = (RichSelectBooleanRadio)child;
        System.err.println("radioButton:: + " + radioButton);
        Object val = radioButton.getValue();
        if(val == null){
            val = radioButton.getSubmittedValue();
        }

        System.err.println("val ::" +  val);
        if( val != null && Boolean.parseBoolean(val.toString())){
            comp = child;
        }
        break;
    }
    findElem(child);
}
```

In this code loop is not terminating after break. 
Could some one help me to identified this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't terminate? Consider reworking your code input, and to also *show* the actual output, and telling us what you would expect instead.

Comment: So, where's the core dump?

Comment: It will not stop recursing at the break since findElem is outside, you miss a return somewhere

Comment: Hi GhostCat, I am expecting on component once condition is true. See I modified the code and return the component once condition met. But still its not working.

Comment: Since you removed the `break` you just invalidated most of the question text and title.

Comment: So correct it to origin changes now let me know when I used return comp in place of break than still its not returning and moving ahead.

Comment: That loop will definitely not continue after that break. Post a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue in a way we can easily test it on our side to also see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static UIComponent findElem(final UIComponent component)
{
    for (final UIComponent child : component.getChildren())
    {
        if (child instanceof RichSelectBooleanRadio)
        {
            final RichSelectBooleanRadio radioButton = (RichSelectBooleanRadio) child;
            System.err.println("radioButton :: + " + radioButton);
            Object val = radioButton.getValue();
            if (null == val)
                val = radioButton.getSubmittedValue();
            System.err.println("val :: " +  val);
            if (null != val && Boolean.parseBoolean(val.toString()))
                return child;
        }
        else
        {
            // Use the result of the recoursive call: if not NULL, return it
            final UIComponent comp = findElem(child);
            if (null != comp)
                return comp;
        }
    }
    // Return NULL if the loop ended without early return
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What did you change? Can you highlight and/or explain the changes?

Comment: Thanks Usagi, I implemented it and its working fine.